# JAVA: Possible to add a runnable thread into a queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, priority-queue, runnable

I recently began working with Threads and I am trying to complete a Java implementation of the Looper class in Android.  Basically I am making a Java class that puts threads into a queue that will then be executed by the Looper class.  I have the code completed for the most part but have an issue with the enqueuing of tasks.

In the Looper class I have the queue declared and my enqueue method:

```
List<Runnable> queue;   

public synchronized void enqueue(Runnable runnable) {
    queue.add(runnable);
    notify(); // signal a waiting thread
}
```

I then created another class called TaskManager to add Tasks into the queue. I receive the error when I call:

```
loop.enqueue(new Task());
```

Where Task() implements runnable and just adds two integers together in its run() method...this is just a test.

The error I receive is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Looper.enqueue(Looper.java:20) (this is the queue.add(runnable))
at TaskMaker.run(TaskMaker.java:16) (this is the loop.enqueue(new Task())
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong and not implementing this right...how should I go about this? Is the way I am enqueuing the task right? Thanks for any help it is much appreciated!

Comment: all Lists make poor queue (incl. LinkedList)

Comment: since you synchronize on queue only, use an already synchronized queue like LinkedBlockingQueue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you initializing the queue variable? like:

```
List<Runnable> queue = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
```